# how would you write complex query in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to run following query in laravel using eloquent model

**This is my raw query in mysql**

```
SELECT `m`.`id` as `mid`,`m`.`code`,`oi`.`id` as `oi_id` FROM `member` `m`,`order` `o`, `order_item` `oi` 
                    where 
                    (`m`.`id`=`o`.`mid` OR `m`.`code`=`o`.`code`)
                    AND
                    `o`.`id`=`oi`.`order_id`
                    AND
                    (`oi`.`from_date` <= '{$selectdate}' AND `oi`.`to_date` >= '{$selectdate}' )
```

**And this is what i have tried in laravel**

```
$record = \App\Member::join('orders','members.id','=','order.mid')
            ->join('order_item','order.id','=','order_item.order_id')
            ->select('id','code','order.id','order_item.id')
            ->where([['order_item.fromdate','<=','{$selectdate}'],['order_item.todate','>=','{$selectdate}'])->get();
```

I am getting confused with the syntax of laravel for same query. please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Typically you'll get a much warmer reception to your question if you show that you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: But i don't know how to deal with this. I need some help thats why i posted this as a question.

Comment: Sure, I understand. But what *have* you tried that didn't work? Or have you not attempted it?

Comment: Have you already got you `Eloquent` models set up?

Comment: Also, what is `$batch`?

Comment: I edited above question. please rewatch the question.